# Using PySerial to communicate with Arduino, how can I tell Python to only execute a function once after receiving certain input?

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I'm using Arduino to send data to Python to then start a computer vision algorithm made with OpenCV, after the computer vision algorithm is finished, I need to send the output back to Arduino to execute a classification technique.
This is part of the code I'm using related to the serial communication:

```
while True:

try:
    data = arduino_serial.readline()[:-2].decode()
    print(data)

    if (data == 'analyze'):
        blockcolor= ColorAnalysis()

        if(blockcolor== 'red'):
            arduino_serial.write(b'0')
            print(ColorAnalysis())
            serial.Serial('COM3', 9600).close()


        else:
            arduino_serial.write(b'1')
            print(ColorAnalysis())
            serial.Serial('COM3', 9600).close()


    elif(data == 'continue'):
        arduino_serial.write(b'1')
        print(data)

except:
    print("Something went wrong...")
```

Ok so basically, arduino sends two different strings, when it sends "analyze", python must run the CV algorithm and return the color it detects, the problem is Python reads "analyze" a lot of times and tries to execute the CV algorithm everytime, and eventually fails to capture the image and the program collapses, so it doesn't output anything. I tried closing the port after writing from Python to Arduino and delaying for a few seconds with time.sleep but it didn't work, the program still crashes.

If I could tell Python to stop reading the serial port for a few seconds after reading the first "analyze" instance, I think it could work, but I don't really know how to do that, and I need the program to run continuously because it's a conveyor belt.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: What are you expecting `serial.Serial('COM3', 9600).close()` to do?  That attempts to open a new serial port object, and then immediately closes it - it has no effect on the port you already have open.  And if the time taken by `ColorAnalysis()` is causing problems, perhaps you shouldn't call it twice every time you receive "analyze" (once to decide the response, once to print).

Comment: Right, I forgot to remove the close() function, I realized it didn't help a while ago.
Calling ColorAnalysis() just once did work actually, it still shows a few errors but the machine is working as expected. Thanks for the input!